# Listbox progressbar

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm using a Listbox that extracts data from an sqldata source on a web application.
The data always appear when the operation of the sqldata source ends.
Is there a way to add a progress bar that will show how long will it take to load?
Thanks

Comment: What exactly causes delay? Is it because of the size of the dataset or the latency?

Comment: the delay is caused by the enormous data that comes from the dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following ->

- Find the number of rows being retrieved.
- Use a background Worker thread to update a progress-bar(the update interval can be set on basis of the size of dataset).

See [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32752415/how-do-i-measure-the-size-of-a-dataset.aspx).